# Using PHP as daemon, lots of network activity, crashing

Tags: php, request, response, daemon, fork

**Backgrond:**

I currently have a daemon written in PHP. I knew PHP wasn't the best solution to this problem when I wrote it, but it's what I had access to at the time and what I'm doing makes PHP more than ideal.

Actually, I am using two daemons in PHP. Both are simple while(true) loops with set_time_limit(0). One likes to crash more than the other (which isn't a problem because I have a cron that restarts it if it ever crashes) and I'm guessing it's because of the increased network activity.

**Anyway, the daemons:**

Daemon 1:
This daemon requests information from an external server, loops very intensely through that data (some 10+ foreach's) and inserts it into a database. It is doing this 24/7. It is critical this daemon is running at 11:59pm each day.

Daemon 2:
This daemon requests the same data. However, when this loops through that data if acts upon certain data found and makes a external network request if it does. It makes requests like this fairly often. Probably around once every few minutes if it's running properly (if it crashes and needs to be restarted or freezes, the requests will build up..) This daemon absolutely loves to crash. Crashes are okay, though. This daemon also likes to freeze where it must be killed to start working again.

**The problem:**

Well, requesting the same data twice (currently like twice per second per script) is extremely inefficient. I need to merge them both into one daemon. However, daemon 1 is critical and needs to be doing it's job. If the more buggy daemon after merging causes the daemon to crash I could have problems.

**So, the question:**

I'm thinking I could create the new daemon to make the requests outside of the script. What I mean is when the new daemon needs to make a network request (that would really slow down the script and likely cause more issues) it calls another script (that wouldn't block the main script). So for example, the new daemon needs to make 20 network requests, it can send those 20 requests all at the same time by calling another script to handle them. This takes the work from the daemon and likely will cause less crashes and I will not need to request the same data twice.

Comment: The solution is to solve your crashing issue rather then layering on additional daemons to restart your daemons. Your daemon should be able to handle things like database or network errors and continue running.

Comment: The second daemon is crashing probably because there's a memory leak somewhere. Try putting your code inside a function and call that function from the while(true) { }. That gives the PHP garbage collector more opportunities to free up memory.

Comment: @Dagon I know C++, but nothing about networking..

Comment: well it does not sound like php is the best language for this

Comment: @Meagar, I thought by externalizing the network requests to a script that can do it's job and then quit would do just that? The daemon will have no opportunities to leak memory.

Comment: @Cleong Creating functions is a good idea and I'll probably do that if I have no better alternative. My main goal was to make the network requests non-blocking and reduce crashing/memory usage (it's bad..)

Comment: @Dagon With all the network requests I have to do and the processing of JSON, I would figure PHP would be the easiest. C++ just feels like it would complicate things.

Comment: You can use stream_set_blocking() to make a stream non-blocking and use stream_select() to see which stream is available for reading. In today's multi-core-CPU world though, it probably makes more sense to spawn an process to handle each request.